# How creating bins for a numeric feature can enables the model to learn nonlinear relationships within a single feature?

Tags: binning, feature-engineering

I understood How binning of numerical feature would help build correlations between the feature & the predictor. For example

For a regression problem, we can bucketize "population" feature into the following 3 buckets (for instance):

```
bucket_0 (< 5000): corresponding to less populated blocks
bucket_1 (5000 - 25000): corresponding to mid populated blocks
bucket_2 (> 25000): corresponding to highly populated blocks
```

Given the preceding bucket definitions, the following population vector:

```
[[10001], [42004], [2500], [18000]]
```

becomes the following bucketized feature vector:

```
[[1], [2], [0], [1]]
```

I took the example from [here](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/feature-crosses/check-your-understanding), and they suggest in the same setting if create bins for 3 different features such as latitude, longitude, roomsperperson, **then we can enable the model to learn nonlinear relationships within every single feature!**

Three separate binned features:

`[binned latitude], [binned longitude], [binned roomsPerPerson]`

I can't understand the learning of "nonlinear relationships within every single feature" because at a time while training only one of the bin(for each feature would be available) would be visible to learning algorithm & not the whole vector, as vector symbolize the input space. Correct me if I am wrong!